# Send the certificate request to the certificate authority of your choice

Tags: certificates

Can anyone explain to me where I should send the certificate request? What is an example of certificate authority of choice? I am taking about Step #2 of the following instructions:

> After you create a CA-signed certificate, you must do the following
> before the certificate is active and you can use the certificate.
>
> 1. From Setup, click Security Controls | Certificate and Key Management, click the name of the certificate, then click Download Certificate Signing Request.
> 2. Send the certificate request to the certificate authority of your choice.
> 3. After the certificate authority sends back the signed certificate, from Setup, click Security Controls | Certificate and Key Management, click the name of the certificate, then click Upload Signed Certificate.
> 4. Click Browse to locate the CA-signed certificate. The CA-signed certificate must match the certificate created in Salesforce. If you try to upload a different CA-signed certificate, the upload fails.
> 5. Click Save to finish the upload process. Click Cancel at any time to not upload the certificate. After you successfully upload the
>    signed certificate, the status of the certificate is changed to Active
>    and you can use CA-signed certificate.

Thank you,
Shaun

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Shaun. It's a bit hard to answer questions when they have so little detail or clarification. Could you maybe explain (or use tags) what feature or functionality you're having issues with ?  If you're new to the site it may be best to have a look at the [welcome tour](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what good questions look like (you can still edit!)

Comment: I am trying to go to the following steps to create and upload a signed certificate. My question is in regard to step #2 of the following instructions:

Comment: @Shaun - Did you happen to read step #3? If so, it gives you a good idea of what #2 is talking about.....Request a certificate from the issuing authority.....

Comment: Question about how to RTFM......

Answer (score 1):

A [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA) is any company that issues SSL certificates. [VeriSign](http://www.verisign.com) is one of dozens of companies offering this service.

The instructions are telling you to create your certificate request locally, send it to the CA, and the CA will send you back a signed certificate.